# Apache2 Modsecurity configuration file error

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, mod-security

I am trying to activate modsecurity by following the official documentation on https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/securing-apache2-with-modsecurity/

Firstly, the file I have is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf instead of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf and when trying to add SecRuleEngine On, I am getting these errors.
[000-default.conf code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER4pJ.png)

This is what is in the 000-default.conf folder:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost:3000 #OWASP Juice shop port
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   SecRuleEngine On

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried removing SecRuleEngine On but then obviously ModSecurity would not be on I believe.

Comment: CRS dev-on-duty here. As the error message already states: do you have the ModSecurity module (mod_security2.so) installed and enabled? 
Btw., I always point to these tutorials written by our co-lead: https://www.netnea.com/cms/apache-tutorials/. Please also have a look at them. They are a very good introduction as well!